# Form Text Boxes Fail to Update With Client Input After Their Value Is Set Server Side

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Apt title 
 
This code demonstrates my confusion:

```
Private Sub loadCss()
    textbox.Value = method.getCSS("existingCssFile.css")
End Sub
```

This method, `loadCss()`, occurs when the page is loaded. It's purpose is to fill a textarea, which has `runat="server"` and `id="textBox"` respectfully, with all the content from a specified css file.

```
Protected Sub saveCss_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveCss.Click
    method.saveCSS(textbox.Value, "fileToOverwrite.css")
End Sub
```

When an `asp:Button` is clicked the latter method fires. However, the string value of  `textbox` is identical to its initial value ignorant of client additions or editions; once the textbox receives its value, it doesn't change server side. 

I have attempted switching from `textbox.value` to `textbox.InnerHTML` but to no avail despite numerous combinations of the two.

## I know the solution now, but can anyone explain *why* this happens?

Comment: Have you call  the `loadCss()` function inside `IsPostBack = False` condition?

Comment: No, I haven't. Frankly, I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Ok you need to call your method inside `page_load` event and have to check the postback for this page is false.

Please try following code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack = False Then
            loadCss()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Quick Q; does the conditional call _have_ to be in the class `page_load`?

Comment: It can be wherever you call loadCss(), as long as it encloses loadCss()

Comment: If this `page_load` event is not available in your code behind file than just add above code in your code behind file.

Comment: can you show me code at where you are calling the loadCss() function?

Answer (score 0):

In the method where you are calling loadCss(), enclose it in:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    loadCss();
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Whoops, I didn't see your comment Bhavesh, sorry! :/

This is the VB equivalent (I think, not an expert on VB). Put it in the method where you are calling loadCss();

```
If Not IsPostBack
    loadCss()
End If
```

Comment: Edited to include VB.